# How can I shrink a img to fit its flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkqfvax1/14/) how can I downsize the img / img-container to be only as wide as its widest sibling div?

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.outer span {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    <span>text</span>
    <span>more text</span>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
  </div>
  
  <div>
     <span>this should determine width</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `width: 100%; max-width: 100%;` on the image will scale it to fit its container, in this case the div, which will automatically expand to match the width of its siblings.

Comment: Related but NOT dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830306/how-can-i-shrink-a-img-to-fit-its-flex-container

Comment: @WildBeard Have you tried it? I can't make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how cross-browser compatible this solution is, but it works on Chrome 64, Safari 11, and Firefox 57.

Give the element containing the `img` a `width: 0; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%;`, and the `img` itself a `width: 100%;`.

Like this:

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.outer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.child {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    <span>text</span>
    <span>more text</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    <img class="img" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="main">
     <span contenteditable>this should determine width</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Another Solution

Use a `background-image` instead of an `img`. This allows us to make the image scale with the width of the widest element in the flexbox.

The trick is to set a `padding-bottom` on the element with the image proportional to the image proportions. In this case the image is square, so I'll set `padding-bottom: 100%; so it creates a square element.

If the image was a wide rectangle, 200 x 100 px, I would set `padding-bottom: 50%`. Or, if the image was a tall rectangle, 100 x 200 px, I would set `padding-bottom: 200%`.

Like this:

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.outer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.img {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    <span>text</span>
    <span>more text</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="img">
  </div>
  
  <div>
     <span contenteditable>this should determine width</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Any idea why the first solution works, though?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS table layout and set `width: 1%` on table and `white-space: nowrap` on text elements.

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  width: 1%;
}
.outer span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div><span>text</span><span>more text</span></div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
  </div>
  <div><span>this should determine width</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is nice, except for one detail :/ The only deviation from the JSFiddle and my actual application need is that the last div width is determined by an image, not a span. The span text needs to wrap in the first division.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked about it for flexbox layout particularly, here is trick playing with pseudo and positions. Note, it only works if you know the image aspect ratio already, example below for a square image.

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.outer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
}

.image:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  /*https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/483779*/
}

.image img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
  </div>
  <div>this should determine width</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your CSS container is already as wide as its widest sibling div. You just need to shrink the border of the picture with paint or photoshop.